# Nodejs - unable to create utf-8 file

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I have created file using this command

```
   var fs = require('fs');
    fs.appendFile('log.csv', 'Hello','utf-8',  function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Now when i check the encoding of file

```
file -bi log.csv
```

The result is

```
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

How do I create a utf-8 encoded file?

Answer (score 13):

I think there are two things here. First you have specified `utf8` incorrectly. It should be

```
fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', 'utf8', callback);
```

That is taken from the docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

`utf8` is actually the default, so you shouldn't even need to pass it as an option

What is new to me, however, is that seemingly you have to write `utf` to the file for it to appear encoded as `UTF-8`

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('log.csv', '\ufeffThis is an example with accents : é è à ', 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

now we see

```
$ file -I log.csv
$ log.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the second paragraph "What is new to me..." . This is exactly what is happening in my case where with everything set up right if I do not include in the file a UTF character the file ends up with ANSI encoding. I wonder if someone knows why...

Comment: not working though `2019-01-30_all_data.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: @ipplos it's because UTF-8 and US-ASCII are indistinguishable for those letters present in ascii. That was the selling point of utf8. It only differs in codepoints >127, so unless you add some, the `file` utility won't know, and default to reporting ascii.